# VBA の正規表現でマッチした文字列を後読みを使わず取り出すには？

Tags: 正規表現, vba

vbaでの正規表現についての質問です。vbaでは調べたところ後読みができないようですが
【～～～～】
のカッコ内の文字だけにマッチする後読みを使わない方法を教えて頂けますでしょうか。

Answer (score 2):

`(.*?)`のように(括弧)を使ってグループ化することで`SubMatches`で取り出せます。

```
Sub ボタン1_Click()
    Dim re As RegExp
    Set re = New RegExp
    re.Pattern = "【(.*?)】" 
    Set matches = re.Execute("hoge【fuga】piyo")
    MsgBox matches.Item(0).SubMatches(0) ' "fuga"と表示される
End Sub
```

**参考資料**

[VBA で正規表現を使う（RegExp オブジェクトのメソッド）](https://excelwork.info/excel/vbaregexpmethod/)